# Ubuntu Boost random_device Installation

Tags: boost, ubuntu

Anyone have an idea on how to get random_device installed on ubuntu? All boost packages from the repo are installed.

The error I am receiving is:
fatal error: boost/random/random_device.hpp: No such file or directory

I'm on ubuntu 11.04

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: is it? The FAQ does state .. _software tools commonly used by programmers_. I'd say Boost definitely qualifies as a software tool used by programmers -- and only programmers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you're looking for is

```
boost/nondet_random.hpp
```

More documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost/random_device.html).

`random_device` was moved to `boost/random/random_device.hpp` in version 1.47.

I would recommend using the standard interface instead of `random_device` as those got accepted into C++11.

Comment: That file doesn't exist either

Comment: make sure `libboost1.42-dev` is installed.  The exact file path is `/usr/include/boost/nondet_random.hpp`  notice there is no `random` directory in there.  The file _is_ there or you don't have boost installed. check [this query](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=natty&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=nondet_random.hpp)

Comment: Found it, thanks. Unfortunately, I'm now getting another error trying to install websocket++. I'll start another question specifying websocket++ as the objective